# How does setInterval() affect performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, web-applications

We are building a web app using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework and have problems showing/hiding tooltips. Apart from trying to find a solution to the actual problem, I have a question regarding the workaround we use in the meantime:

Performance-wise, is it generally a bad idea to use setInterval()?

How can I measure the performance impact caused by this?

Are there better ways to constantly check for the presence of elements and remove them?

```
// temporary workaround to remove unclosed tooltips
setInterval(function() {
    if ( $('.tooltip.in').length > 1 ) {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This'll be fine until you solve the issue, but I would look into actually solving the issue, if I were you.

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the performance implications is for the setInterval function itself are, or do you mean the performance of your particular use of it? The performance of using setInterval will depend on which function you execute each interval.

Answer (score 1):

if you're really, *really* worried about performance, using a live nodelist might be faster :

```
var tooltipInNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip in");
var tooltipNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");

setInterval(function() {
    if ( tooltipInNodes.length > 1 ) {
        $(tooltipNodes).remove();
    }
}, 1000);
```

This is unlikely to make much of a difference though, and as has been mentioned, using setInterval with long intervals (a second is big, 4ms is small) is unlikely to have any major effects.

Comment: live nodelist is expensive IMHO

Comment: err... do you have any sources other than IMHO?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU (old video I admit, but depending of the browser could be useful)

Comment: Seriously, if you're going to link to an hour long video, tell me where he talks about nodelists. Second comments like "live nodelist is expensive" are totally useless, because it depends on the circumstances. If I was looping over all the elements, I would prefer a static list (avoid re-evaluating the query with every element access), but that's not what's happening here!

Comment: With jquery, the query is re-evaluated and a full static list is constructed every second. With the live nodelist, only the length part of the query is re-evaluated (cached in some browsers), so in this case, it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is better to avoid this technic, but until you find a real solution, you can optimize this workaround.

Create a not anonymous function and call it, you'll avoid "context function creation" every second.

You can also optimize jQuery selectors by caching and specify the tag name.

```
setInterval(tmp_workaround, 1000);

function tmp_workaround() {
  var $selectors = $('[TAG IF ALWAYS THE SAME].tooltip.in');

  if ( $selectors.length > 1 ) {
    $selectors.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you select the elements outside of your function if you want to cache them?

Comment: don't think so, because you have to "refresh" the cache every second and potentially get new open elements, it useful because without caching, you parse the DOM twice. First time to check if length is more than 1, another time to remove all elements.

Comment: why are you removing .tooltip.in when the original removes .tooltip?

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, I'll add them.

Comment: How is anything cached here? And the non-anonymous function doesn't do any good as well. Besides the tag name (which I'm not even sure of) I can't see any optimisation here.

Comment: the tag name allow to retrieve only wanted tags instead of ALL DOM, then searching coresponding elements... Could be very useful, especially if your DOM is big. For caching, look at my second comment.